# How can I create a backup file. iso like Edubuntu?

Tags: boot, backup, dvd, iso

I want to create a DVD boot can setup like Edubuntu boot. This is the second time I have installed Edubuntu on my pc, but every time I install, I have to upgrade all packages and language. (Almost 400 - 500 Mb). Is it possible to make a bootable DVD of my current installation so that I don't have to upgrade all the packages next time? (It can use for USD boot too)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a program called Remastersys ive used it several times and works like a champ.
You can back up an entire system, including user data, to an installable Live CD/DVD
or Create a customized Live CD/DVD (a remaster) of Debian or Ubuntu and its derivatives.

http://www.remastersys.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://lichota.net/~krzysiek/projects/ubuntu-livecd-customization/).